# WinForms DataGridView Alternative

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I need to populate a list that has 3 columns.

First: Icon Image.
Second: A string.
Third: A string.

I started to wire up a DataGridView and it seem awfully large and powerful for my needs. I am not interested in displaying data in a grid similar to a spreadsheet and I do not require all the functionality that comes with this control. Is there a better alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go for the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) in [View.Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx) view, as this is similar to the view that you see in Windows Explorer when in Details view.

Create a form and place on it an `ImageList` and a `ListView` named `imageList1` and `listView1` respectively. Then place the following code into the forms load method:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Image");
listView1.Columns.Add("Text1");
listView1.Columns.Add("Text2");

listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"c:\windows\explorer.exe");
imageList1.Images.Add(icon);
var item = new ListViewItem();
item.ImageIndex = 0;

var subItem1 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
subItem1.Text = "Text 1";
var subItem2 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
subItem2.Text = "Text 2";

item.SubItems.Add(subItem1);
item.SubItems.Add(subItem2);

listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

The code really couldn't hurt for some tidying up, but it calls out quite explicitly what it's doing and should hopefully make it quite clear how to use a `ListView` for this purpose.

Comment: the View.Details view is an important element of this post. Read and head.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx). You'll want to use the [Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns.aspx) property and Details mode.